# Core Data Schema Design

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I'm trying to write an iOS application that tracks how much weight your lifting at the gym but I'm struggling to create my Core Data schema. At the moment i have an Exercise Entity that stores info about a specific exercise (e.g. Bicep Curl) and i have a workout Entity that just has a name & image. The workout entity has a many to many relationship with the exercise entity. what i need to incorporate is 'session' functionality - the ability for a user to complete a workout and store the weights he/she lifted in a particular workout. E.g. i want to say that i completed my 'Leg Day' workout and lifted these weights for each exercise. So my Core Data looks like this at the moment.

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxr6o.png)

How would i go about storing the session data? I feel that the session must have a one to one relationship with a workout but that doesn't let me add results for each exercise in the workout... I also think i might need a dictionary to store the weights for each exercise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i have never really learnt about databases before.

Thanks

EDIT: Ive changed my schema to look like this

[schema2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eucRF.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, regarding your schema2, in database design it is typically bad practice to have relationships that form a "circle". Also, if an entity only has a single attribute, it could be reduced to an attribute of its parent.

I would probably approach your design a bit differently.

You should split your exercise entity into Exercise and Exercise_History or something similar. Then you would remove any relationship between Session and Workout and have a one to many between Session and Exercise_History.

Also, if Lift only has a single attribute, it probably shouldn't be its own entity.

If you approach it like that, you should get the desired relationships and functionality.